# delete duplicated row and merge cell value mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which has three columns:

```
Name           | Email               | BDate
---------------------------------------------------------
John Doe       | jdoe@company.com    | June 1, 1980
Kelly Smith    |                     | June 2, 1983
Richmond White | rwhite@company.com  | 
John Doe       |                     | 
Kelly Smith    | ksmith@company.com  | 
Richmond White |                     | June 3, 1984
```

What I want to do is to delete duplicate name and merge the cell value. I want my table to look like this:

```
Name           | Email               | BDate
---------------------------------------------------------
John Doe       | jdoe@company.com    | June 1, 1980
Kelly Smith    | ksmith@company.com  | June 2, 1983
Richmond White | rwhite@company.com  | June 3, 1984
```

How would my query look like to return my desire table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39ba0/1)**

```
SELECT t1.Name, 
       MAX(t1.Email) Email, 
       MAX(t1.BDate) BDate
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

Result:

```
|           NAME |              EMAIL |        BDATE |
------------------------------------------------------
|       John Doe |   jdoe@company.com | June 1, 1980 |
|    Kelly Smith | ksmith@company.com | June 2, 1983 |
| Richmond White | rwhite@company.com | June 3, 1984 |
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i need. Appreciate much.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the following query to create a new table and then delete the old table:

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Email) AS Email, GROUP_CONCAT(BDate) AS DBate
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your reply. :)