# mysql Merge Cells where rows duplicate

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so:

```
Name           | Note                |
--------------------------------------
John Doe       | Smells like cheese  | 
Kelly Smith    | Smells like ham     | 
Richmond White | Smells like apples  | 
John Doe       | Sounds like trumpet | 
Kelly Smith    | sounds like tuba    |
```

I found part of my answer here: [delete duplicated row and merge cell value mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17081640/2062352) , but that only returns the first occurence of the data in the second column. I need concatenate it like so:

```
Name           | Note                |
--------------------------------------
John Doe       | Smells like cheese  | 
               | Sounds like trumpet |
--------------------------------------
Kelly Smith    | Smells like apples  | 
               | Sounds like Tuba    | 
--------------------------------------
```

Furthemore, I'd like to keep the line break in the 'note' column.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for string aggregation like this

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(Note) note
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY name
```

This will produce the following output:

```
+----------------+----------------------------------------+
| name           | note                                   |
+----------------+----------------------------------------+
| John Doe       | Smells like cheese,Sounds like trumpet |
| Kelly Smith    | Smells like ham,sounds like tuba       |
| Richmond White | Smells like apples                     |
+----------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0a1a2/2)** demo

---

> *Furthemore, I'd like to keep the line break in the 'note' column.*

It's a matter of presentation and should be done in your client code. For example in php you can `explode()` `note` column values while you're iterating over the resultset and emit the proper line breaks (it may be `\n` if it's in text mode, `</br>` or separate cell in a table or `div` or something else if it's HTML output).

But if you want to you change a delimiter to anything other than a comma (e.g. to `\n`) you can do it with `SEPARATOR`clause

```
GROUP_CONCAT(Note SEPARATOR '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! The SEPERATOR clause was great because I wanted to edit the data used as output by a plugin, without affecting the plugin code itself.